# Heteroscedasticity test for random effects model in (Stata)

Tags: random-effects-model, heteroscedasticity

I'm using panel data in my study.

So far, already done the analysis with xtreg, for re and fe, and Hausman test yielded that I should use re.

However, when I wanted to test for Heteroscedasticity, I could not find a command specified for re.

Comment: Did you look at the residuals from the xtreg model? Are they showing any signs of heteroskedasticity? You can always get standard errors that are robust to heteroskedasticity using the `robust` option in your `xtreg` model statement.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Do you mean the command xtreg y x, re, can show heteroskedasticity?

For fixed effect, the command is xttest3, but it can not be applied for random effect. This is why I was confused, as I failed to find a command that suits RE.

Comment: @ErikRuzek, can you please look into this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/458826/breusch-and-pagan-lagrangian-multiplier-test-for-random-effects-for-random-effec

Comment: I am not familiar with tests for this. I was referring to a visual inspection. I'll post some Stata code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site, Joseph. I have not personally used tests for heteroskedasticity in the residual errors, however, you can get a read of whether you have any problems by looking at a couple of plots of your residual values. One common plot is a residual vs. fitted values plot, which you generally like to see having a nebulous cloud pattern. If you switch from `xtreg` to `mixed`, below I've pasted code to pull the residuals and fitted values from your model and then plot it:

```
mixed dv iv || clusterID: 
predict sresid, rstandard // standardized level 1 residuals
predict predval, xb // predicted outcome value
scatter sresid predval // cloud graph – hopefully no pattern
```

You can also examine the normality of your residuals using a Q-Q plot, which plots the residuals as a function of a normal distribution, but stretched out along a line. Major deviations of residual points from the normal line are a problem.

```
*Level 1 residuals vs. normal scores graph
qnorm sresid // residuals should fall along the line
```

Although not all Stata-specific, there are [many](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html) good [resources](https://ademos.people.uic.edu/Chapter18.html) for [diagnosing](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/589590-checking-assumtions-for-repeated-measures-analysis) any abnormality in your residuals.